# Is it OK for the author of a question to post a comment of another user as an answer?

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483874/how-to-bind-to-property-of-property-in-wpf?rq=1), the author a section **SOLVED**, because a user's comment was his solution. He requested the other user to post his comment as an answer, but he never did.

Would it be OK for the author of the question (or even a third user) to post it himself as an answer so it has better visibility?

Comment: He *did* post it as an answer, in a very clumsy way.  It was deleted by a moderator 4 years ago.  If he doesn't want to take the time to write it up properly then there's little anybody can do about it but post the answer himself.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, more precisely, he posted an answer saying that the comment answered his question; he didn't post an answer stating what the answer to the question was.  That is of course why it was deleted by the moderator.  (I say this because others can't see the deleted post.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn any answer into a *community wiki* post by checking the respective box when posting. This will allow almost anyone to edit, and you will not gain any reputation from upvotes on that answer.

This is a great way of making a comment answer more visible without receiving reputation for someone else's work. However you need to cite or even quote when copying others' ideas or content.

It is not necessary to do this for all comment answers. It is probably not too useful on questions with no answers and just a few comments.

Comment: While many people choose to mark such an answer as CS as a convention, it is not required.  Citing the author, on the other hand, is actually required in such a situation.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can re-post another user's content, you simply need to cite the content appropriately.  All content posted to the site gives everyone this right as a part of the licence used for user-contributed content.

Additionally, we want questions to be a place where people go to see what the question is, and answers to be where they go to see the answer, therefore you should edit out the answer from the question in cases like these; the content belongs in an answer (just make sure the content exists in an answer before removing it from the question).